# Alternatives of lists vs Alternatives of strings

Tags: list-manipulation

Obviously I am missing something obvious.

I have:

```
lis = {"a"}|{"b"}|{"c"}
```

but I want:

```
lis2 = "a"|"b"|"c"
```

Thanks as always for suggestions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `lis[[All, 1]]` or `First /@ list`. See [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and [`First`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can also [`Apply (@@@)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) [`Sequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html) at level 1:

```
Sequence @@@ lis
```

> "a" | "b" | "c"

Also

```
## & @@@ lis
```

> "a" | "b" | "c"

Alternatively, use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) to replace `List` with `Sequence`:

```
lis /. List -> Sequence
```

> "a" | "b" | "c"

Additional methods:

```
MapAt[Sequence &, lis, {All, 0}]
ReplacePart[lis, {_, 0} :> Sequence]
lis[[All, 0]] = Sequence; lis
```

all give `"a" | "b" | "c"`.